# How to animate the table view cell textLabel

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

i have this code, I want to animate this. Some one helps me please.? When i run the code it shows it normally !! i just want to show it as an animated textLabel. which slowly comes in.
somebody please help me out, there is animation property for cell.ImageView is available. but not for textLabel.

```
cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(55, 143, 88, 24);
```

i tried this , but its not working,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.036 animations:^{
                   cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(55, 143, 88, 24);
                    } completion:nil];
                [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Try by creating new label and setting its frame.

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora i am working with table view cell noh.?, how can i create.

Comment: I am asking you to customize the cell

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        cell.textLabel.frame =  CGRectMake(55, 143, 88, 24);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

The alpha property of a UILabel is animatable. You can set the alpha to be 0 (totally transparent) when you create it, and then animate the alpha to 1.0 (totally opaque). This can be achieved like this:

First set the alpha of your cells textLabel to 0.0 in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, as well as whatever other code you want here as well.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %lu", indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.alpha = 0.0;

    return cell;
}
```

Then you can animate it with a class method on `UIView` called `animateWithDuration`. I put it `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` just for this example, but you should be able to do it wherever you need to.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        cell.textLabel.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Yes of course, silly of me. Forgot to take into account the fact that you were dealing with a UITableView, and not just a normal UIViewController. I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

    cell.textLabel.frame =  CGRectMake(55, 143, 88, 24);

    //You should force them to layout subviews again
    [cell layoutSubviews];

}];
```